# Version error in AWS Elastic beanstalk for Multicontainer Docker Configuration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, phabricator

Trying to link mysql with phabricator in Elastic beanstalk with 
help of dockerrun.aws.json file as shown below.

But it sows error as

```
[Instance: i-cdbaf100 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] 
Command failed on instance. 
Return code: 1 
Output: Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed. 
For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Can someone please help in resolving this?

Here is the Dockerfile.aws.json file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "mysql-database",
      "image": "mysql",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 400
    },
    {
      "name": "phabricator-only",
      "image": "yesnault/docker-phabricator-alone",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 400,
           "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "mysql-database"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is activity log file

```
[2015-05-09T08:12:17.546Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:17.820Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:17.820Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.086Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.086Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteConfig] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.089Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteConfig] : Completed activity. Result:
  Recreated directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/.
  Generate appsource url file at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/appsourceurl.
  Generate container config file at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.089Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp1] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.089Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Recreated directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.089Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.332Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2/Infra-WriteApplication2] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.333Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2/Infra-WriteApplication2/Infra-WriteApplication2] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.333Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2/Infra-WriteApplication2/Infra-WriteApplication2/Command 01downloadVersion] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.385Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2/Infra-WriteApplication2/Infra-WriteApplication2/Command 01downloadVersion] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.385Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2/Infra-WriteApplication2/Infra-WriteApplication2] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.385Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2/Infra-WriteApplication2] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.407Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/InfraWriteApp2] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.407Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.646Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.647Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.663Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.663Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.663Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/00clean_dir.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.843Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/00clean_dir.sh] : Completed activity.
[2015-05-09T08:12:18.843Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01unzip.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.121Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01unzip.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  {
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "mysql-database",
        "image": "mysql",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 400
      },
      {
        "name": "phabricator-only",
        "image": "yesnault/docker-phabricator-alone",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 400,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 80,
            "containerPort": 80
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          "mysql-database"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.121Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02docker_db_check.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.124Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02docker_db_check.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  0||/
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.125Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.426Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2015-05-09T08:12:19.426Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] : Activity failed.
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.427Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.427Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2015-05-09T08:12:19.427Z] INFO  [24016] - [CMD-AppDeploy] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-AppDeploy failed.
```

Comment: can you clarify what you are asking

Comment: What solution stack are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OP javvaji kiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3999760/javvaji-kiran) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137895/version-error-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-multicontainer-docker-configuration/30137945?noredirect=1#comment48387877_30137945):

> The service was not available for the location which I selected.
>   But service are available in other locations

---

Original answer:

It depends on the error message you have, but note that [all values of a `Dockerrun.aws.json`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) are normally in double quotes.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "janedoe/image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "1234"
    }
  ],
....
```

Check if the error persists after adding double-quotes in your own `Dockerrun.aws.json`

That said, the exact error message is:

```
Activity execution failed, because: Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version
```

See [this source](https://github.com/DjedStudios/djedstudios.github.io/blob/master/03build.sh#L21-L25):

```
# Dockerrun.aws.json verson checking
# right now only one valid version "1"
if [ -f Dockerrun.aws.json ]; then
    [ "`cat Dockerrun.aws.json | jq -r .AWSEBDockerrunVersion`" = "1" ] || error_exit "Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment" 1
fi
```

So try with `"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",`

Also, I don't see "links" in the [Valid keys and values for the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html).

Comment: Then time to check the activity log

Comment: yeah .. now i added log file too

Comment: but i can see the resource for my requirement inawsdocs it self http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html

Comment: The service was not available for the location which i selected .But service are available in other locations ... Thanks alot @VonC

Comment: @javvajikiran OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @javvajikiran Could you explain what you mean with "the service was not available for the location which i selected"? I'm getting the same error...

Comment: I mean at that time , For the region I selected there is no availability of Mutli Docker container service.

Comment: The double-quotes fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you get the error "Invalid Dockerrun.aws.json version, abort deployment. " it's also possible that you're not using the correct Solution Stack.

In my case I was using the Single Container Solution Stack and I should have been using the Multicontainer Solution Stack. Once I configured my environment to use the Multicontainer Solution Stack this error went away.

A list of Solution Stacks can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.docker

Answer (score 3):

You have to select multi-container type when creating your environment. May require deleting and creating new environment as upgrading from single-container is not available right now.

Make sure it says "running Multi-container Docker" on Dashboard under Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was using wrong solution stack.
We should be using `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.8 running ECS` or a version of it.
I was using `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.8 running Docker`.

List of available stacks can be get using `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks`